# Linker error: already defined in my project when I don't define it at all

Tags: c++, c, windows, linker

I am trying to build a C project in Visual C++ 2010 Express as C++ so I can create a C++/CLI .net wrapper for it.  It compiles fine, but the linker tells me that swprintf(...), vswprintf(...), _swprintf_l(...), and _vswprintf(...) are already defined.  The strange thing is that it says they are already defined in an .obj file that I made, and I am sure that I did not define them.  In fact, I don't even call any of them.  Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Some clarifications:
This library is being written in straight C and built and run in OS X, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, and Linux.  Porting it to Windows as a .net assembly is the challenge.  I read that C libraries must be built in C++ to be given a C++/CLI wrapper.  In getting it to build as a C++ project, I had to make a few tweaks (such as malloc casting) but it should still maintain C compatibility.

*** FINAL UPDATE ***

I don't know how many hours I have wasted trying to make a .net wrapper for the file parsing library I am writing.  I have tried it several times and every time it fails miserably.  This time I did get farther than ever before, but I still could not get it to work.

What I had originally envisioned was a 3 project solution:

1. an unmanaged static libary, built in C
2. a managed .net wrapper, built in C++/CLI
3. a managed winforms app, built in C#

I quickly learned that the express editions of Visual Studio give you exactly what you pay for them and don't allow you to mix projects of different languages in a single solution.  In order to do that, I would have to pay $800 for VS Pro and that is NOT happening!

I adapted to this by deciding to write the simple app in C++/CLI.  Even so, it simply would not work.  Apparently, I would either have to link the .obj files from part 1 (which doesn't work, because it cannot compile C files with /clr) or build part 2 with /clr:safe (which created all kinds of other problems).

I really don't know if this is a limitation of the useless Express editions of VS or if this would even be possible with the absurdly expensive versions (strange that $800 gets you VS Pro, but $700 gets you all of XCode and a Mac Mini to run in on!  Microsoft Dev Tax anyone?!?) but either way, I've had enough.  My library works great in OS X, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Linux, and OpenSolaris, but not Windows, and until MS releases free dev tools that are actually useful and actually provide a way to use PORTABLE code (this works in), I just won't care.

Thanks to all of you who gave advice and tried to help.

jorj

Comment: Something smells fishy. Do those names appear *anywhere* in your source files? If so, where?

Comment: No, but I do have several calls to snprintf(...), which I have defined as _snprintf(...) for windows, which is probably redefined as one of the offending function names in stdio.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the preprocess-to-file option. This will tell you quickly where the function come from !

May be you're using the _tcs-versions of them ?

Comment: Good idea.  I didn't see a preprocess option in the Build menu so I figured Express didn't allow it - I never thought to look under properties.  From this output, I see that swprintf(...) is defined from a swprintf.inl file.  This is probably included in stdio.h, which I include in most, if not all, of my .c files. There is a "#pragma once" a few lines up, but apparently it is being ignored.  Shouldn't header files declare (just a prototype) functions and not define (provide all code) them?

Comment: @sirjorj: In C ,I should think so. Maybe a good question to post separately.

Comment: @sirjorj: but you´re using C++/CLI thus then it's perfectly legal. (are you sure that they aren't .cpp files ?)

Comment: I am not building this as managed code.  These are .c files being built as c++ (/TP) because I read that unmanaged code must built as c++ to make a .net wrapper out of it.

Comment: @sirjorj: then you're  effectively using C++.

Comment: Well... kind of.  It should be compatible as both.  I am just not using any C++ features.  I added some additional info to the OP.

Comment: #sirjorj: try to build with "default" instead of /TP. I think it's probably not needed.

Comment: It builds!  Now to get the managed C++/CLI project to link to it.  I won't be convinced that this is the right answer until I get the .net wrapper working, but until then, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can check that all your projects and files are using the same Common run time library (Properties | C\C++) and check the Runtime Library setting.  Including both the Multi-Thread debug DLL (\MDd) CRT and Multi-Threaded DLL(\MD) or other such mix up with the CRT libraries could cause something like this.

Can you post the linker output? does it mention anything about \NODEFAULTLIB?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by linking objects that were generated using either different options or different runtime libraries.  I would guess that some of your objects were compiled with debugging options enabled and others were not or something similar.

Comment: It is straight C so there are no 'objects' in the literal sense, and it is just one project, so all the files should have the same settings as far as I know.

Comment: @sirjorj: Here 'object' refers to the internal *.obj files used by the compiler.  Try a "rebuild all"-like option?

Answer (score 0):

Because they are automatically included in the CRT runtime vs2010 links to.

If you try to export function that wrap around these stuff, maybe prefix them with a `c_` ?

Answer (score 0):

@sirjorj--
swprintf is defined in wchar.h. What headers are you #including?